# How to loop through dataset and replace values of a different sequence of columns for each row?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

**Problem**: I have a dataset (please see sample dataset and code below) with columns all assigned a value of 0. I would like to assign the value of 1 to a specific sequence of columns, of which the start and end column numbers I calculated and stored in the columns `zFlagStart` and `zFlagEnd`. When I try to do this via a for `1:nrow(df)` loop, I get the following error: `numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used`

Sample code to create dataset

```
#create sample dataset
r1<-c(0,0,0,0,0,1,3)
r2<-c(0,0,0,0,0,3,5)
df<-as.data.frame(rbind(r1,r2))
names(df)<-c("Flag1","Flag2","Flag3","Flag4","Flag5","zFlagStart","zFlagEnd")
```

Sample dataset created:

```
   Flag1 Flag2 Flag3 Flag4 Flag5 zFlagStart zFlagEnd
     0     0     0     0     0          1        3
     0     0     0     0     0          3        5
```

Sample dataset desired:

```
   Flag1 Flag2 Flag3 Flag4 Flag5 zFlagStart zFlagEnd
    1     1     1     0     0          1        3
    0     0     1     1     1          3        5
```

Failed for loop and error:

```
for ( i in 1:nrow(df)){
  
  df[i, c(df$zFlagStart:df$zFlagEnd)] <- 1
}

Warning messages:
1: In df$zFlagStart:df$zFlagEnd :
  numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
```

Edit: Here is the solution thanks to @ThomasIsCoding:

```
df2<-as.data.frame( t(apply(df, 1, function(v) replace(v, gsub("\\D", "", names(v)) %in% seq(v["zFlagStart"], v["zFlagEnd"]), 1))))  


   Flag1 Flag2 Flag3 Flag4 Flag5 zFlagStart zFlagEnd
r1     1     1     1     0     0          1        3
r2     0     0     1     1     1          3        5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `apply` below

```
df[] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(v) replace(v, gsub("\\D", "", names(v)) %in% seq(v["zFlagStart"], v["zFlagEnd"]), 1)
```

which gives

```
> df
   Flag1 Flag2 Flag3 Flag4 Flag5 zFlagStart zFlagEnd
r1     1     1     1     0     0          1        3
r2     0     0     1     1     1          3        5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a sequence of numbers from `zFlagStart` and `zFlagEnd` along with their corresponding numbers in one matrix which can be used to subset `df` and replace with 1.

```
tmp <- Map(`:`, df$zFlagStart, df$zFlagEnd)
df[cbind(rep(seq(nrow(df)), lengths(tmp)), unlist(tmp))] <- 1
df

#   Flag1 Flag2 Flag3 Flag4 Flag5 zFlagStart zFlagEnd
#r1     1     1     1     0     0          1        3
#r2     0     0     1     1     1          3        5
```